# QuickSort with ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, quicksort

I am trying to implement a *quicksort* using `ArrayLists`. However I am not sure how to create one `Arraylist<Integer>` with all the integers in it. I feel like there is a method I could use to easily do this. Here is my code

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> quicksort(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int min, int max) {
    int pivot = (min + max)/2;
    if (arr.size() <= 1) {
        return arr;
    }
    else {
        ArrayList<Integer> less = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> greater = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i : arr) {
            if ( i < arr.get(pivot)) {
                less.add(i);
            }
            else {
                greater.add(i);
            }
        }
        return quicksort(less, min, pivot) + arr.get(pivot) + quicksort(greater, pivot + 1, max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `addAll()`:

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(less.size() + greater.size() + 1);
result.addAll(less);
result.add(pivot);
result.addAll(greater);
```

Comment: @TejaswiRana it adds all the values in `less`, then the `pivot` and then all the values in `greater`. Can you elaborate what exactly is unclear, or what you're asking? I'm not sure I understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method which will do the merging of the `Lists` for you. Something like this

```
private List<Integer> mergeLists(List<Integer> list1, Integer element, List<Integer> list2) {
    List<Integer> mergedList = new ArrayList<>();
    mergedList.addAll(list1);
    mergedList.add(element);
    mergedList.addAll(list2);
    return mergedList;
}
```

And call this method in your return statement.

```
return mergeLists(quicksort(less, min, pivot), arr.get(pivot), quicksort(greater, pivot + 1, max));
```

Note that this is just an example and you can modify it as per your needs. I initially had a `vararg` of `List<Integer>` but found that it won't be useful in this case.

In case you wish to merge more than 2 lists(only lists of the same type), then something like this can be done.

```
private List<Integer> mergeLists(List<Integer>... lists) {
    List<Integer> mergedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<Integer> list : lists) {
        mergedList.addAll(list);
    }
    return mergedList;
}
```

And use the method like this.

```
List<Integer> combinedList = mergeLists(list1, list2, list3, list4);
```